# Why my ArrayList<String> is NOT sorted correctly?

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, android-sqlite, comparator

I've been searching online and trying, but I didn't find the solution.

I have the following ArrayList:

{ Cate1, Cate3, Cate6, Cate2, ...., thru Cate10 }

I gave tried the following solutions:

```
public ArrayList<String> GetAllCategories_ByAscOrder() {
    db = getWritableDatabase();

    ArrayList<String> Category_ArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(Category_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, Category_List + " ASC");

    if(cursor != null)
    {
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            String CATEGORY = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Category_List));
            Category_ArrayList.add(CATEGORY);
        }
    }

    cursor.close();
    return Category_ArrayList;
}
```

And these:

```
Collections.sort(CATEGORY_LIST, new Comparator<String>(){
    public int compare(String obj1, String obj2)
        {
           return obj1.compareToIgnoreCase(obj2);
        }
    });
}

//OR THIS:

Collections.sort(CATEGORY_LIST, new Comparator<String>(){
    public int compare(String obj1, String obj2)
        {
           return obj1.compareTo(obj2);
        }
    });
}


//OR THIS:

Collections.sort(CATEGORY_LIST, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

But ALL of them gave me the same sorting results:
Cate1, Cart10, Cate2, Cate3,, etc.... Cate9

I want the sorted list to be like this:

**Cate1 thru Cate10**

Can someone please guide me on how I can achieve this?

Thank you very much

Edit:

I forgot to mention that I let the users freely name their Category Names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do like this :

```
          Collections.sort(list , new Comparator<String>(){
              public int compare( String a, String b ){
                  // if contains number
                  if( a.substring(4).matches("\\d+") && b.substring(4).matches("\\d+")) {
                      return new Integer( a.substring(4) ) - new Integer( b.substring(4) );
                  }
                  // else, compare normally. 
                  return a.compareTo( b );
              }
          });
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but the if statement was never called.  Thanks

Comment: your list contains 'cat1,cat5...cat10' data like this ryt?

Comment: Yes, Cate1, Cate5, etc. thru Cate10.  Thanks

Comment: @Dante  put `4` instead of `3` since your string `Cate` length is `4`.

Comment: OH WOW, it works.  There are so many genius in this world, and you are one of them.  THANK YOU so much!

Comment: Nice custom comparator!

Answer (score 4):

Its sorted by [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).
If you want it sorted like that, you should switch to using two digits,

eg. `Cate01`, `Cate02`, ...

Note that this happens in Windows/Linux filesystems too (if you have numbered files in a folder).

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the results you got are correct - Cart10 alphabetically comes before Cart2 (since 1 comes before 2).

Try adding leading 0s to your numbers before sorting: Cart01, Cart02, etc - though you'll need to pad with leading zeros to make sure you cover the largest you expect your list to get (if it'll be over 100 elements, you'll need more zeros).

Alternatively, why not just store it as `ArrayList<Integer>` and prepend with "Cart" when you go to output the results? How you ultimately solve this depends on what you want to use the values for...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment.  I let the users freely naming their Category names, so I have no control on how they name them.  Can you elaborate more details on ArrayList<Integer> please?  Thanks again

Comment: It just looked like you were storing numbers appended to "Cart" - sorting a list of numbers will sort them in numerical order instead of alphabetical order. If the names of these are user-determined though, then this won't be useful. As a note, sorting like that is consistent with other places that sort names of things alphabetically, such as filesystems.